# Find nth most common value from the column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named table which has column named fruits. Fruits can have values like below:

**fruits**
apple
orange
banana
apple
apple
banana

What is the easiest way to fetch the nth most common occurring value in this column?

Output:
when n=2, 2nd Frequent
Query should return banana

Comment: What do you mean "highest"?

Comment: With 5 apples, 5 bananas, 3 oranges and 3 peaches, what would you return for n=2?

Answer (score 3):

You can group by identity and select the second in the descending order by count with `limit` and `offset`:

```
select fruits
from your_table
group by fruits
order by count(*) desc
limit 1 
offset 1;
```

P.S.: You shouldn't name the table `table` as this is the keyword in sql.

Comment: Could you think of any reason why it gives incorrect results on my data, For example, when I am giving offset 1, it is giving me 4th most common fruit, when I am giving offset 3, it is giving me 13th most common fruit. I am not sure why s thi happening?

Comment: @atp hmm, hard to say. Can you show it on db fiddle?

Comment: I test it on [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6bc73e4e4560dff724e17d4edd4e6df8) and its works.

Comment: This is just a copy of Gordon's earlier answer. `LIMIT 1` is the common Postgres shorthand for standard SQL `FETCH FIRST1 ROW ONLY`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean the n'th most *frequent* value.  If so, you can use aggregation and offset:

```
select fruit
from t
group by fruit
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only offset <n - 1> rows;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9e8ca7d94f1cea59d72420f76476d6f9) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: i am very new to sql, is this in posgres?

Comment: It throws an error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 5: FETCH 1 ROW OFFSET 0;

Comment: @atp . . . I fixed the syntax and included a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff in the fiddle also it is showing same error.

Comment: @atp . . . That is really strange.  I must've deleted the space before the "1" and not noticed it.